# Is there a way to remove spaces from T-SQL commands and still execute them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

I am trying to execute a command but I need the spaces removed.

Here's the command I want to execute, but it has two spaces:

```
DROP TABLE Table_1
```

What I want to do is to convert it to a form which has no spaces. I thought I could use concatenation and the CHAR string function to produce a string to execute:

```
'DROP'+CHAR(32)+'TABLE'+CHAR(32)+'Table_1'
```

I tried this and passing it to EXEC but this is apparently not valid:

```
';EXEC('DROP'+CHAR(32)+'TABLE'+CHAR(32)+'Table_1');--
```

I then considered constructing the string over many lines @declaring temporary variables, but for that it seems I would again need spaces.
Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: For me the interesting question is: Why do you want to do that? Would it be ok to use TABs instead?

Comment: Out of curiosity,why do you want to remove space?

Comment: There are missing single quotes in your exec statement.

Comment: I am injecting it through an input field. The input field has validation preventing spaces (and forward slashes)

Comment: Ah, so you essentially wanted us to help you with conducting SQL injection? Nice.

Comment: @AndriyM - There are legitimate reasons for SQL injection. e.g. exposing vulnerabilties in existing code. If the application is public facing and vulnerable it is probably only a matter of time anyway.

Comment: @WeylandYutani - In what context are you performing this?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Fair enough, there was probably too much presumption on my part. But in this case it would be great to know straight away we weren't participating in anything malicious and the OP didn't clarify that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use empty multiline comments instead of whitespace:

```
DROP/**/TABLE/**/Table_1
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: +1 I didn't think it was going to be possible without any white space characters at all.

Comment: Nice - I'll remember that, not sure when I might need it, but interesting nonetheless

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned this, ... I can't use forward slashes either...I'll mark this as answer if someone doesn't find an alternative that doesn't use forward slashes